# Create entity and attach on same operation is failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this code:

```
$entity = new Role();
$data = $request->json()->all();
$entity->fill($data);
foreach ($data['permissions'] as $permission) {
    $entity->perms()->attach($permission['id']);
}
$entity->save();
```

This is failing with an integrity contraint as it seems that the attach is setting null on the role_id. The role.id is an `increments` column.

Of course I can move the save before the `foreach` and save the entity again after that:

```
$entity = new Role();
$data = $request->json()->all();
$entity->fill($data);
$entity->save();
foreach ($data['permissions'] as $permission) {
    $entity->perms()->attach($permission['id']);
}
$entity->save();
```

, but that would require to use a transaction.

Is there a more elegant way than saving twice?

Comment: because befor saving the entity has no Id, and i think you can remove the second save in the second code !!

Comment: Thanks! So I'm looking for something like "attach later" ...